# Measure decaying faster than exponential

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am following Glimm & Jaffe's *Quantum Physics* where they define a generating functional
$$S\{f\} = \int e^{i\phi(f)} d\mu.$$
Here $d\mu$ is a Borel probability measure over the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $f \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (the space of smooth functions with compact support). They impose the condition that for every set of test functions $f_j \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $j = 1,2, \ldots, N$, and complex numbers $z = \{z_1, \ldots z_N\}  \in \mathbb{C}^n$ the function
$$z \mapsto S\Big\{\sum_{j=1}^N z_j f_j\Big\}$$
is entire on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

They describe this condition as "$d\mu$ decays faster than any exponential". I do not fully understand this. What does it mean for a measure to decay faster than an exponential and how does the above condition imply this happens for the measure $d\mu$ above?